# Cost surface in R: topographic distance betwen cells' centers in place of planar distance

Tags: raster, r, distance, cost-surface

**Aim**

Calculating slope-dependent walking distance taking into account topographic distance NOT planar distance between cell centers.

**Tool**

'gdistance' R package

**Issue**

I do not really know how to code to consider topographic distance in place of planar distance between cells' centers

**Executable code**

What follows is after https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i13/0

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package = "gdistance"))

altDiff <- function(x) x[2] - x[1]

hd <- transition(r, altDiff, 8, symm= FALSE)

slope <- geoCorrection(hd)

adj <- adjacent(r, cells = 1:ncell(r), pairs = TRUE, directions = 8)

speed <- slope 

speed[adj] <- 6 * exp(-3.5 * abs(slope[adj] + 0.05))

Conductance <- geoCorrection(speed)
```

In the previous code, the Tobler's hiking function has been applied and the speed of movement has been calculated when moving between adjacent cells.

The very last line of code takes into account the distance between cell centers because moving with the same speed along a diagonal connection between cells takes longer than moving along a straight connection.

What I am not sure of is about how to proceed to take into account not the "planar" distance between cell centers, but the topographic distance. I do know that the Pythagorean theorem should be used in the calculation, but I really cant wrap my head around how to implement that in the context of the above code.

Comment: Tobler's hiking function accounts for differences in altitude and `geoCorrection()` accounts for the variant distances between cells. What else do you want to implement?

Comment: Hi. To answer your question: I'd like to take into account topographic distance, which is different from planar distance between cells' centers. See this for example: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/understanding-path-distance-analysis.htm

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what Tobler's hiking function does? `geoCorrection()` corrects for the distance on a flat terrain and Tobler's hiking function adjusts for the topography. Tobler does it in a more elaborate way than the Pythagorean theorem does. You can of course account for further factors like road quality, wind patterns etc. by adjusting the transition function or Tobler's equation. The `gdistance` package mentions alternative transition functions and the `movecost` package implements alternative hiking functions.

Comment: I think I do. What the code I posted does, is to apply the Tobler's hiking function considering the incline (i.e., slope) between adjacent cells. Thus, the cost (in this case expressed in terms of time) incurred when moving between one cell to another is determined. Then, the geoCorrection() corrects the cost to account for horizontal distance (i.e., the cost of moving along diagonal is larger than along cardinal directions). That said, what I am after is along the line of what some software do, i.e. correcting the cost for movement(s) over topographic surfaces.

Comment: see here (under 'Path Distance formula'): https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-the-path-distance-tools-work.htm